# Java Graph Implementation without data structures

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I had an interview Samsung. I'm a fresh graduate and they asked me to program an application such that:

- it's a graph of cities , each city can reach the other (all vertices can reach each other) , there is some vertices if you moved(Deleted) they will affect the graph (it will be split and some of the vertices will never reach each other)

The question is, determine the vertices that if they are removed, it will disconnect the graph (affect a vercticy or more from reaching all others).

*without using any data structure (no queue, no array list) just arrays are allowed.

The input is like:

V = number of vertices.
E = number of edges

and the edges in the input file are like

1 2 3 4 3 6 4 8

1-2 are 1 relation between 1 and 2 and it is bidirectional so both ways.

How can this question be solved, and do you think its hard for a fresh graduate?

Comment: `without using any data structure` meaning no array?

Comment: Can you explain better the edges? I don't follow

Comment: `"1-2 are 1 and its bidirection so both ways"` could you please clarify what that means? I don't understand it

Comment: _"determine the vertices that if they are moved , it will affect the graph"_, since the vertices are part of the graph, the graph is always affected.

Comment: @JornVernee what the OP means is: *"if that vertex would be removed, it would result in two non-connected graphs"*

Comment: Interesting assignment. But you understand, that normally stackoverflow isn't something where you just drop requirements; actually people expect you to show **your work** to solve the problem. You see, what if this isn't just an interesting puzzle ... but maybe your homework; and your dropping it on us; instead of trying to solve it yourself?! So, at least for the future: "please solve this for me" doesn't make up good questions.

Comment: @Jagermeister this is not my homework i have done the interview and did not solve , but its just for my knowledge and my self , the interview is gone , and no need for the solution any more .

Comment: @SariLakkis Unfortunately your edits removed the usual way to express this problem. It's a very simple, well known problem of finding the articulation points  (or cut vertices) of the graph, for which there are many question/answers out there.

Comment: Knowing the number of edges and number of vertices you an use arrays as they are fixed-size. Not using more abstract data structures probably is for their ease of analizing the work done. The problem solving requires the entire trajectory. But aside from the algorithmic solution, they in fact caused that now one also needs to consider the limited data structures. Not too difficult though. Just the time. What can be simpler than a City with an array the length of all cities of connected. Or such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a class Vertex (or Node) and map the Edge between two Vertices as the assoziation between two instances. This would be a bit naive, but would work if you shall only set up easy operations like removing.

```
public class Vertex {

    int number;
    Vertex[] vertices; // you have to look yourself if array is big enough

}
```

Now, each vertex has an array of Vertices he is connected to. You can realize a bidirection if you add a Vertex in this vertices array and then add the calling vertex to the array of the added vertex:

```
vertex.add(new Vertex(1)); //internally, it will be looked if array is big enoguh and then the add method will do its work

...

public void add(Vertex v) {
    //add into vertices
    ...
    v.add(this);
}
```

To remove a vertex, the remove operation should delete the references on this vertex in the vertices-arrays of the other Vertices objects.

A more conceptual solution could be to provide a second class Edge that has a start and end vertex.

Maybe that helps you a bit.

Comment: unfortunately  , they did not allow me to make any class , all the work was on the main of the program

Comment: then you can use 2dimensional arrays as adjacent or incident matrices. thats a common representation of graphs